# UITabBarController is loading two tabs at application start

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing a multi device App with separate views for iPhone and iPad. Within my App I'm using a UITabBarController with four tabs of content as the mainView.
The first tab contains a UINavigationController the second tab contains a UIViewController. Third tab is like first tab but with other NIB and Class-Files. And fourth tab is like second tab but with other content.

In every viewDidLoad Method I wrote something to console like "[currentview] was loaded" and currentview was replaced with an identifying name for the view which was loaded.
If I start my App on iPhone then the console shows me that without any user interaction the first tab and the third tab (both UINavigationController) both were loaded. In detail the third tab was loaded before the first tab.
If I start my App in iPad then only the first tab is loaded like it should have to be. Except for implementing NIB files targeted for iPad I use the same source code at the beginning of my App.

In AppDelegate_iPhone.m I only add the UITabBarController.view as a subview to window. Same procedure is done in AppDelegate_iPad.m

I already googled about this and found out that calling a controllers.view results in loading the view but programmatically I don't call neither the view of the first tab nor the third tab. This is done by UITabBarController in his natural way (didn't change anything for this controller). So I'm a bit confused why my App loads the third tab on iPhone. Because of this matter I had to remove some code done in viewDidLoad of the third tab because this code only had effect if the tab was nearly about to display.

I hope anybody has had the same issue and could tell me a solution or maybe a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake.
Creating a new project with a UITabBarController and four tabs with the given constellation showed up that the error wasn't a general one. After realizing this I went step by step through my MainWindow_[ver].xib comparing the differences between iPhone and iPad version.
I found out that in MainWindow_iPhone.xib the third tab was declared as a UINavigationController. Within this NavigationController I had a UITableViewController whose contents came from a class/nib linked via Interface Builder. Compared with the MainWindow_iPad.xib (where the error didn't occur) I found out that I used a UIViewController within the iPad version instead of UITableViewController.
After changing the iPhone version to UIViewController the error disappeared. Hooray :)

To approve if this error occurs everytime a UITableViewController was used in another tab than the first one I edited the newly created project and changed the third's tab UIViewController (within the UINavigationController) to a UITableViewController. As expected the third tab was loaded before the first tab.
Additional info: although in MainWindow_[ver].xib I declared a UIViewController to be loaded the specific implementation was a UITableViewController subclass. Seems to work because UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController but still strange why the superclass has to be specified in the MainWindow_[ver].xib